# Fantasy story where the protagonist's habitual memorization of train schedules helps him kill a monster

Tags: story-identification

I was doing a browse through TV Tropes, when suddenly a vivid memory of a story I read popped out at me. The male protagonist, for some reason, has habitually memorized train schedules since he was a child. Some part of me wants to say that he does so as a coping mechanism, perhaps to provide a sense of order to the world, or because of a personal trauma related to train, but perhaps just a facet of his personality. This comes in handy later in the story when he (and I think a female companion) are being pursued by some monster or creature, and he uses his memorized knowledge of the train timetables to ensure that he crosses a track at just the right time such that the pursuing monster and hit (and I believe killed) by the train. I believe this was set in the 20th century, and that magic was not a common thing, rather that the male protagonist had been dragged into it after a mundane life.

Unfortunately, that's pretty much all that I can remember about this other than that I think it was part of a larger novel, and that I think it was at least five years ago, probably more than ten.

Comment: Memorizing trivial minutia like train schedules sounds very much like Sherlock Holmes. Obviously not your answer, but that was the first thing I thought of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is Clive Barker's book *Weaveworld*.

As you remember, it follows a normal human called Cal who becomes involved with a group of magical beings called the Seerkind.

There were a few monsters, but the one that you're thinking of is "The Rake" - as [Wikipedia mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weaveworld):

> A hideous phantasm of a former sorcerer named Domville [...] He is resurrected by Immacolata as a terrifying boneless demon and sent to assassinate the Seerkind which he does, claiming the life of Lillia before being destroyed by a passing train after being lured onto the tracks by Cal and Nimrod.

I don't remember that he memorised the schedules as a coping mechanism, but simply that the train passed very close to the end of the garden of the house where he grew up.

Comment: Ah, and I see now that it was [a childhood feat of memory to memorize the train schedules](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Weaveworld/kgQhEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=weaveworld+mooney+train+schedules&pg=PA80&printsec=frontcover). I should be able to accept this in another few minutes.